# How good is it to write a query like this?

Tags: sql, database, oracle, query-performance

```
select 
a,
b,
(select x from table3 where id = z.id) as c,
d
from 
table1 z, table2 zz
where z.id = zz.id;
```

I know that the query can be simplified easily like below:

```
select a,
b,
c.x,
d
from
table1 z,table2 zz, table3 c,
where z.id = zz.id and z.id = c.id;
```

but i want to know what is the performance impact or extra execution happens in case1 or they both have same performance? Asking just for knowledge.

Comment: Not comparable. If table3 has no match, the first query will return null for that column, while the second query will return no rows at all.

Comment: Tip of today: Switch to modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax! Easier to write (without errors), easier to read an maintain, and easier to convert to outer join if needed!

Comment: @jarlh i am assuming to compare when there is data. Well i understand that its not a good practice to write query like this, but i am looking into the legacy code where such coding style was used.

Comment: Well, if it has been working for years, don't touch it!

Comment: If you use a scalar subquery (as in your first statement), Oracle will cache the results. That means that if you have a relatively small number of distinct z.id values there could be a performance benefit since it only has to run the subquery once for each distinct value.

Comment: @Boneist thats helpful, thanks

Comment: @jarlh i asked for my information, if you can provide any input on performance analysis most welcome, but "Don't touch it" is not the solution of anything, its my curiosity to know and gain knowledge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use a correlated subquery (which is fine), then you should do:

```
select a, b,
       (select t3.x from table3 t3 where t3.id = z.id) as c,
       d
from table1 z join
     table2 zz
     on z.id = zz.id;
```

Important changes:

- Qualify all column names (I don't know where `a`, `b` and `d` come from).
- Use explicit `join`.

You can also write this query as:

```
select a, b, t3.x, d
from table1 z join
     table2 zz
     on z.id = zz.id left join
     table3 t3
     on t3.id = z.id;
```

This query is subtly different from the previous one.  The previous one will return an error if the subquery returns more than one row.  This one will put each such value in a different column.

That said, the Oracle optimizer is quite good.  I would be surprised if there were any noticeable performance difference.

Answer (score 1):

The first query, with a correlated sub-query, will always return data even if table3 is empty. You need an outer join to get the same result:

```
select a,
       b,
       c.x,
       d
from table1 z
join table2 zz on z.id = zz.id
left join table3 c on z.id = c.id
```

Answer (score 1):

Using join the query has been more readable

But performance is that same

```
select a,
b,
c.x,
d
from table1 z
join table2 zz on z.id = zz.id
join table3 c on z.id = c.id;
```

Comment: `the performance is the same` - that's not necessarily true, though. Oracle can and will do scalar subquery caching, so if there's a relatively low number of distinct z.id values, Oracle can run the scalar subquery once for each distinct z.id value and reuse it whenever it comes across that value elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

If your subquery is returning a single value based on a single input, it is a scalar subquery.  A scalar subquery MIGHT improve performance for your query.  It will do so under a couple of basic conditions.  First, if z.id has a relatively low number of possible values.  Scalar subquery processing will cache up to 254 values, if I recall.  Second, if the rest of the query is returning a relatively high number of rows.  In this case, if you only return a few rows, then the caching will not have an opportunity to help.  But if you are returning a lot of rows, the caching benefits will build up.

Others have already highlighted how your original queries are not quite equivalent.

See more on scalar subqueries here -> [Scalar Subqueries](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/issue-archive/2011/11-sep/o51asktom-453438.html)